# Help with my network setting/connection. I need to connect my Laptop to my Desktop

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

I'm not good doing network on my computer. I've been searching on the web and youtube for tutorials on how to properly connect/share files from desktop to laptop using wireless connection.

**Here's the scenario:** I bought a D-Link router and plugged my internet source and then from my router it connects to my Destop (Lan 1) using RJ-45 and a cable. The internet is currently working well for my Desktop and Laptop. In my laptop I can access the internet using wireless connection and my desktop it uses a cable from the router.

**The Problem:** I've been trying to setup a homegroup (both in Laptop and Desktop) but I can't find any of them to connect. I also can't find any of them in my network. I'm guessing that my Laptop and Desktop are not properly configured to connect to each other. It just connect to the internet...

**What I'm trying to achieve:** I need to share files from my Desktop to Laptop or vise versa. I don't know how to do this, any tutorials online would be good. I also don't want to use DropBox or similar services...

**My System**: My Desktop and Laptop is using Windows 7 Ultimate.

Please advice. Thanks!

---

screenshot:

My Desktop:
[image]

My Laptop:
[image]

Comment: can you provide screenshots of your lan properties of your desktop and laptop I want to make sure that you have checked all the options on that page. You need to configure your router on the lan side if you want static addresses but it may not really be required.

Comment: In order to share files between your computers you dont even have to setup a home network but it's supposed to be easier when you use a home network

Comment: Added the screenshots above. If I missed some details, please do let me know and i'll try to add it here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is your router configured to give static or dynamic IP address? I ask because if static, try changing it to dynamic and see if the computers can see each other again.

Another thing you could try is to make sure that the network type on each computer is set to "Home" so that Network Discovery will be turned on. Then try the Homegroup setup again.

Once Homegroup is properly configured, you can share any libraries you want. You can create a library in Windows 7 and add whatever folders to it. Then you can share that library via Homegroup and let the OS handle all the permissions/sharing/etc.

Comment: thanks... how can i know if my IP is static or dynamic? and how do i change it? I tried accessing my router here 192.168.0.1. But I don't know where to find it.

Comment: What brand and model is your router?

Comment: It's DLink wireless n150. this one (http://www.productwiki.com/upload/images/d_link_dir_601_wireless_n_150.png) thanks for helping me out :)

Comment: Look at the image on this website: http://portforward.com/routergui/Dlink/DIR-601/Network_Settings.htm   If the DHCP box is checked, then you have dynamic IP address allocation set up.

Comment: It's enabled Here's the a screenshot http://i52.tinypic.com/whd46r.jpg what do i do next?

Comment: Since it seems that DHCP is already properly enabled, please do the following:1.Turn off the router. 2. Follow the directions at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357 to reset your TCP/IP stack. 3.Make sure your computers are turned off. Then turn on your router and wait for it to boot up. 4.Turn on your computers and verify that the network type is set to Home. 5.Try creating a Homegroup in Windows. If one is already created on the network, remove it and recreate it. 6.Add your computers to the Homegroup and see if you can access the Homegroup shared files.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is map one drive of the computer to the other.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Create-a-shortcut-to-map-a-network-drive

gives all the steps necessary to achieve this.

Instead of having just one of your computers connected via wireless, I suggest doing either both wired or both wireless, if possible.

Comment: Thanks for you Quick response. For now that wouldn't be possible that I can connect each of them with same connection type (wired or wireless), I don't have an extra cable for my laptop, and my pc don't have wifi Adopter. Mapping the drive is one that i'm looking, but i think it only works if you can already see your computer in the network. I still can't see the other computer in my network... any idea?

Comment: Try making a folder on one of your computers "shared" and then find the name of your computer. You can then usually map to it by putting the address, i.e. `\\MY-PC-NAME\PATH-TO-FOLDER-ON-DISK`

Comment: I tried mapping a folder in my lapop then tried accessing it in my desktop. it said "The system cannot find the drive specified"